# Auto decrement textarea in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a textarea with auto increment row.
And i want to set auto decrement when i delete my text . How can i do it?

Here is my code:

```
<textarea name="content" rows={this.state.rows} className="text-area"
       placeholder="Content" onInput={this.autoHeight} onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.content}/>
```

```
    autoHeight = (elem) => {
        if (elem.target.scrollHeight > this.state.rows * 15) {
            this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows + 1 });
        }
    }
```

```
        this.state = {
            rows: 6,
            content: ''
        }
```

Comment: do you want to reset number of rows to 6 when you delete all the text inside the textarea?

Comment: xample i have 16 rows with 3 last rows are empty. i want to set my rows = 13

Comment: why is rows multiplied by 15 in the if condition? is it the line height?

Comment: @rock-bottom yes, elem.target.scrollHeight return the entire height in pixel of my text area. 15 is height per line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of setting `rows` attribute on the `textarea` and using `autoHeight` to increase the height of the `textarea`, set `min-height` on the `textarea` and use `onChange` event handler to increase or decrease the height of the `textarea`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      content: '',
      minHeight: 100
    }
  }

  onChange = ({ target }) => {
    const paddingTop = parseInt(getComputedStyle(target).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));
    const paddingBottom = parseInt(getComputedStyle(target).getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'));
    const verticalPadding = paddingTop + paddingBottom;

    target.style.height = 0;
    target.style.height = Math.max(target.scrollHeight - verticalPadding, this.state.minHeight) + 'px';

    this.setState({ content: target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          name="content"
          placeholder="Content"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.content}
          style={{ minHeight: this.state.minHeight, padding: '10px' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works like a charm. all i do is set height = 0 and reset height = scrollHeight